# How to correctly process a string with escapes in Go?

Tags: string, go, memory, escaping

I am creating a program, which is processing and calculating sizes of open-source repositories and libraries, and saving the data to database for further analysis.

- I have an input string: `github.com/Azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`.
- Parsed to a format: `github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`
- Then I parse that into a format `/home/username/dev/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` which is a valid path in my filesystem, where I've downloaded that particular Go Library.
- After that, I am passing that path to the `gocloc` -program (https://github.com/hhatto/gocloc)
- And parse the result.

But the issue is, when I am saving that string `/home/username/dev/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` into a variable, Go actually adds another escape to the string I am saving so it's actually `/home/username/dev/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/\\!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` in memory. (fmt.Println - for example removes that)

[image: Screenshot from VSCode Debugger, when this is in memory.]

Problem is, when I am passing that string as an argument to os/exec, which runs `gocloc` and that path string, it runs command with two escapes - and that's not a valid path.

Is there any way to work around this? One idea for me is to just a create shell script on what I want to do

This is the function, which parses `github.com/Azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` to a format `github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` - and after thats saved into a variable, and the variable has one more escapes, than it should have.

```
func parseUrlToVendorDownloadFormat(input string) string {
    // Split the input string on the first space character
    parts := strings.SplitN(input, " ", 2)
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return ""
    }

    // Split the package name on the '/' character
    packageNameParts := strings.Split(parts[0], "/")

    // Add the '\!' prefix and lowercase each part of the package name
    for i, part := range packageNameParts {
        if hasUppercase(part) {
            packageNameParts[i] = "\\!" + strings.ToLower(part)
        }
    }

    // Join the modified package name parts with '/' characters
    packageName := strings.Join(packageNameParts, "/")

    return strings.ReplaceAll(packageName+"@"+parts[1], `\\!`, `\!`)
}
```

After, string is parsed to a format: `/home/username/dev/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`

that is passed to this function:

```
// Alternative goCloc - command.
func linesOfCode(dir string) (int, error) {
    // Run the `gocloc` command in the specified directory and get the output
    cmd := exec.Command("gocloc", dir)
    output, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    lines, err := parseTotalLines(string(output))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return lines, nil
}
```

Which uses this parse function:

```
// Parse from the GoCloc response.
func parseTotalLines(input string) (int, error) {
    // Split the input string into lines
    lines := strings.Split(input, "\n")

    // Find the line containing the "TOTAL" row
    var totalLine string
    for _, line := range lines {
        if strings.Contains(line, "TOTAL") {
            totalLine = line
            break
        }
    }

    // If the "TOTAL" line was not found, return an error
    if totalLine == "" {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("could not find TOTAL line in input")
    }

    // Split the "TOTAL" line into fields
    fields := strings.Fields(totalLine)

    // If the "TOTAL" line doesn't have enough fields, return an error
    if len(fields) < 4 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid TOTAL line: not enough fields")
    }

    // Get the fourth field (the code column)
    codeStr := fields[3]

    // Remove any commas from the code column
    codeStr = strings.Replace(codeStr, ",", "", -1)

    // Parse the code column as an integer
    code, err := strconv.Atoi(codeStr)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return code, nil
}
```

What I've tried:

- Use gocloc as a library, didn't get it to work.
- Use single quotes instead of escapes, didn't get it to work, but I think there might be something.

One way to get around this, might be to create separate shell script and pass the dir to that as an argument, and get rid of the escapes there, I don't know ...

If you want to observe all the source code: https://github.com/haapjari/glass and more specificly, it's the files https://github.com/haapjari/glass/blob/main/pkg/plugins/goplg/plugin.go and function `enrichWithLibraryData()` and utils functions, which are here: https://github.com/haapjari/glass/blob/main/pkg/plugins/goplg/utils.go (the examples above)

Any ideas? How to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\!` isn't an escape sequence, it's two characters. Go doesn't add any extra escapes, it is not storing it with an extra escape in memory, and `fmt.Println` does not remove anything (because there is nothing to remove). If there is an extra backslash, you are adding it somewhere else.

Comment: But isn't it whats happening here? Or is this just a go debugger, or vscode debugger thing?

https://imgur.com/a/g3DJFZR

I am getting an error that the path with two escape characters doesn't exist, so my other function is getting a string with a two backslashes. I don't get it ... :/

Comment: That's the debugger displaying the value as a quoted string, which requires escaping the backslash. Go does not alter the string in memory.

Comment: Are you certain the path actually contains `\!` in the first place, and it's not just displayed as that where you are inspecting it, because `!` is a special character in the shell? For example, the argument in the command `ls foo/\!azure/bar` does not contain a backslash, it escapes the `!` in the shell.

Comment: It should I think? 

Heres an overview of the debugger on the error I am getting:

https://imgur.com/a/mRRqzQc

(The lstat thingy under the "output", which is outputting the print of glocloc command ..)

and heres what I have locally:

https://imgur.com/a/Ac2YOWj

and this works locally:

https://imgur.com/a/kma0L2A

and this gives same output, thant the go code, which state is represented in the debugger:

https://imgur.com/a/7S1aQiF 

which would argue, that the string in memory would have two backlashes. But im not completely sure, whats going on here.

Comment: No, it does not add backslashes in memory.  The picture of the command output is exactly the same as the example I showed above, there is no backslash in the path, you are just escaping the ! in the shell. You could wrap the argument in single quotes and not have to use a backslash at all.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll do that. I managed to get the solution working without backlashes, using a raw string literal instead of string literal. 

This works: ` `/home/haspe/uni/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` ` 

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an input string: `github.com/Azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`.
>
> Parsed to a format: `github.com/\!azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`.

---

Your parser seems to have error. I would expect `Azure` to become `!azure`:

`github.com/!azure/go-ansiterm v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1`.

---

> [Go Modules Reference](https://go.dev/ref/mod)
>
> To avoid ambiguity when serving from case-insensitive file systems, the $module and $version elements are case-encoded by replacing every uppercase letter with an exclamation mark followed by the corresponding lower-case letter. This allows modules `example.com/M` and `example.com/m` to both be stored on disk, since the former is encoded as `example.com/!m`.

---

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! 

Expanding from this answer, I hardcoded a string using a raw string literal instead of string literal:

` `/home/haspe/uni/glass/tmp/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/go-ansiterm@v0.0.0-20210617225240-d185dfc1b5a1` `

and passed that to gocloc function, and it's working!

Winning! 

Thank you both very much.